# spanning trees of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Assume we have a simple connected graph G, how would start a prove of the following statement?

For any edge of G, there is a spanning tree of G that contans it.

I have decided that this is a true statement but I am not too sure about how to prove it. 
Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a connected graph, and $u v$ an arc in it. Let $T$ be a spanning tree of $G$. If $u v \in T$, there is nothing to do. If not, as $T$ is a tree, there is exactly one path from $u$ to $v$ in $T$. If an arc is deleted from this path, and the arc $u v$ is added, the result is connected and has the same number of edges as $T$, i.e., it is again a tree spanning $G$.

Comment: Far simpler than my solution.

Comment: Your'e wellcome. Nice problem, BTW.